# compile header files defines a template class which also includes other header files

Tags: c++, templates, hyperlink, g++

JUST to make it clear : it is **different** from the problem that we must define functions of template class in the header file.

**UPDATE** ： if you need the real source code, you can download it here : https://Near@bitbucket.org/Near/compile_error.git

I implement a double list class.

```
// list.h //
class list {
  //...
  void insert(...);
};

// list.cpp //
#include "list.h"
void list::insert(...) {
  ...
}
```

I also implement a template class which include the list.h

```
// template_class.h //
#include "list.h"
template<class T>
class temp_class {
  list l;
  void func();
}

void temp_class::func() {
  //...
  l.insert(...);
}
```

Now I write a test.cpp file which include the template_class.h and call the func function

```
// test.cpp //
#include "template_class.h"
int main() {
  temp_class<int> t;
  t.func();
  return 0;
}
```

I compile like this

```
g++ test.cpp list.cpp -o test
```

The compiler complains that test.cpp : "undefined reference to insert".
Why can't it work? How to solve this error?

---

FYI : If I include the content in list.cpp in list.h and just compile test.cpp, it works. But I don't think it is a good idea.

Comment: No, it should not. I do implement all things of template class in the header file.

Comment: The summary looks correct, but, of course, a summary is not real code.

Comment: Please give a small non-working example for reproduction. That means, exactly the content of the files for whose the compiler fails. The three dots are not exactly what you have, are they?

Comment: True. I'm sorry. However, in that case you haven't provided enough detail: if all `list::insert()` members are defined in the implementation, the code should link. With the vague notation it is hard to tell whether that's the case.

Comment: Note that your `temp_class::func()` is incorrectly defined: you need to have `template <class T> void temp_class<t>::func() { ... }` Is your `list::insert(...)` declared `inline` by any chance?

Comment: I just add the link of the source code.

Comment: Near, nobody is going to download your source code. Reduce it to a small sample that exhibits the problem you're describing and post it here, by which I mean edit it into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When compiling your code I immediately get the warning:

```
list_double.h:14:15: warning: inline function ‘void list_double_node::list_double_insert_first(list_double_node*)’ used but never defined [enabled by default]
void inline list_double_insert_first(list_double_node* entry);
```

That is, your code is actually akin to this [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/):

```
// list.h
class list {
public:
  inline void insert(int);
};
```

.

```
// list.cpp
#include "list.h"
void list::insert(int) {
}
```

.

```
// template_class.h
#include "list.h"
template<class T>
class temp_class {
  list l;
public:
  void func();
};
template <class T>
void temp_class<T>::func() {
  l.insert(17);
}
```

.

```
// test.cpp
#include "template_class.h"
int main() {
  temp_class<int> t;
  t.func();
  return 0;
}
```

The fix is: either remove the `inline` or define the function in the header. The rules for `inline` are actually pretty much the same as those for template: whenever an `inline` function is used, its implementation has to be provided.

Comment: Thank you. I thought the warning will not affect it.